# An umbrella Scala project. How to create multimodules project with multiple versions of scala, and libs?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there a way to create an umrella project and to specify what version of scala, or lib/s to use for each module independently?

I'd like to create a multi-module project.

1. Each module covers one scala version.
2. Each module may include submodules each of which includes some set of libs.
3. Non of modules interact with each other.
4. Each of which has it's own build.sbt file, and describes it's own set of libs.
5. There should be ability to build each of these modules to get a jar file.

It may have a different shape, the idea is to keep all the libs I'm playing around with  in one place.

```
|root
|
|-|A
| |-|B
| | \build.sbt(lib1)
| |
| |-|C
| | \build.sbt(lib2)
| \build.sbt(scala_version="2.13.1")
|
|-|D
| |-|E
| | \build.sbt(lib1)
| |
| |-|F
| | \build.sbt(lib4)
| \build.sbt(scala_version="3.1.1")
|
build.sbt
```

I've already tried:

```
1. .aggregate(A,B) in the 'root' build.sbt
2. crossScalaVersions := supportedScalaVersions
3. define build.sbt files for each module independently.
```

Answer (score 0):

### The solution for IntelliJ IDEA users could be found **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcRXD.png)**.

---

1. **Add** all the desired **modules** using sbt.
2. Press **ctrl + alt + shift + s**
3. **Group**(right button, then 'Change Module Names...') them.

---

### [image]